# How to find cumulative distribution function given the first ocurence probability?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let the function $a(t),~ t \ge 0$, denotes the probability that there
is an arrival in the current period (period $t$) given that no customers
arrived in the previous $t-1$ periods. Assuming
the inter arrival times to be independent
and identically distributed, with $A$ as the generic
inter arrival time. How to find the cumulative distribution of $A$?

Comment: I find this confusing. Arrival times are often denoted by a continuous variable, t, but here you call it a "period", and speak of "t-1" periods between 0 and t-1 (when there are t of them, if t was an integer). If t was continuous, then A would be a random variable with an exponential distribution (given that the times between arrivals are iid), and the cumulative would be the integral of the exponential...

Comment: You are correct if we consider the continuous time queueing model, where the inter arrival times are represented by continuous random variables. But the present model is a discrete time queueing system, where the time axis is slotted into equal intervals, called periods. At most one customer can arrive in a period.  Even if in the continuous case, I couldn't understand your claim that `A` will be exponentially distributed if inter arrival times are iid. I think `A` will be exponentially distributed only in case of Poisson arrivals.